# How to make a FQL query with Python? 

Tags: python, facebook-fql

I do:

```
str('https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=') + query
```

then this should be queried and get the JSON data converted in Python, but how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use something like [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#module-urllib) or [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/pycurl.html) to do http request and then use [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) library to decode received data. I believe documentation on each module is very detailed, so it should be sufficient.